# Meteor: Update 4x nested array object inside a collection

Tags: javascript, arrays, mongodb, meteor, collections

I am trying to figure out how I would update an object I have that is inside of a nested array in one my collections.

Here is a picture of how the data is structured.

[image]

How can I replace the last object on the list ">4: Object" using a Collections.Update method on the server?

What all information would need to be passed to the server method to be able to locate the object?

Also the object does have a unique _id:

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25741120/update-nested-array-in-meteor

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30866537/meteor-mongo-updating-nested-array